# iPhone displays plain and html in newsletter email

Tags: iphone, email, mime

I've set up an multipart mime email containing an area for text- and one area for html-version of a newsletter. All works fine excepting my iPhone. It is displaying the text version first followed by the HTML version. But I dont have any ideas why ... :-/

Here is the PHP:

```
$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Test';
$bound_text = 'boundary42';

$headers = "From: sender@sender.net\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
        . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";

$message = file_get_contents('mime.file');

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The file content:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=boundary42 

This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.
--boundary42 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Text goes here     

--boundary42 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family: arial, 'Arial';">
        html goes here
    </body>
</html>

--boundary42--
```

Answer (score 0):

See [MIME type to satisfy  HTML, email, images and plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631856/mime-type-to-satisfy-html-email-images-and-plain-text/20851485) and [Mail multipart/alternative vs multipart/mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902455/smtp-multipart-alternative-vs-multipart-mixed)

What you have built is a multipart/*mixed* container with two things in it: text and plain. For mixed, it is correct to render both.

What you probably want is a multipart/*alternative* container to hold those two things.