# What's the most appropriate way to format an email?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, html-email, email-attachments

With JavaMail, I am building messages with the following format

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| multipart/related                              |
| +---------------------------+  +-------------+ |
| |multipart/alternative      |  | attachments | |
| | +-----------+ +---------+ |  |             | |
| | |text/plain | |text/html| |  |             | |
| | +-----------+ +---------+ |  |             | |
| +---------------------------+  +-------------+ |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

ASCII art attributed to the OP of this question: http://www.coderanch.com/t/503380/java/java/Java-Mail-text-html-attachment

I felt that this would be the correct format, since the attachments (image/gif, application/pdf, etc.) are important in understanding the message as a whole. However, I've been doing some researching and have found that oftentimes `multipart/mixed` is used.

**Should I replace the `multipart/related` section with `multipart/mixed`? If so, why?**

An example message in this format would be as follows:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
    boundary="----=_Part_6818257_562311419.1408632937947"

------=_Part_6818257_562311419.1408632937947
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_6818256_1953685207.1408632937947"

------=_Part_6818256_1953685207.1408632937947
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is my message!
------=_Part_6818256_1953685207.1408632937947
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><strong>This is my message!</strong></html>
------=_Part_6818256_1953685207.1408632937947--

------=_Part_6818257_562311419.1408632937947
Content-Type: application/pdf;name="document.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <attachment0>
X-Attachment-Id: attachment0

< insert lots of base64 encoding here >
------=_Part_6818257_562311419.1408632937947--
```

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: @Nabin Assuming that we programmers are problem solvers on many fronts, I'd say, yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some more searching, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631856/mime-type-to-satisfy-html-email-images-and-plain-text), which practically matches my concern here.

According to the RFC spec, it appears that the best way to structure email messages is in the following format:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| multipart/mixed                                           |
| +--------------------------------------+  +-------------+ |
| | multipart/alternative                |  | attachments | |
| | +------------+ +-------------------+ |  |             | |
| | | text/plain | | multipart/related | |  |             | |
| | |            | | +---------------+ | |  |             | |
| | |            | | | text/html     | | |  |             | |
| | |            | | | image/gif     | | |  |             | |
| | |            | | +---------------+ | |  |             | |
| | +------------+ +-------------------+ |  |             | |
| +--------------------------------------+  +-------------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

With this configuration of messages, email clients can decide on the alternative type of message to display. In addition, `multipart/related` constitutes what is related to the message portion of the email, not including attachments.

For more clarification on `multipart/related` comes [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Related):

> A multipart/related is used to indicate that each message part is a
>   component of an aggregate whole. It is for compound objects consisting
>   of several inter-related components - proper display cannot be
>   achieved by individually displaying the constituent parts. The message
>   consists of a root part (by default, the first) which reference other
>   parts inline, which may in turn reference other parts. Message parts
>   are commonly referenced by the "Content-ID" part header. The syntax of
>   a reference is unspecified and is instead dictated by the encoding or
>   protocol used in the part.
>
> One common usage of this subtype is to send a web page complete with
>   images in a single message. The root part would contain the HTML
>   document, and use image tags to reference images stored in the latter
>   parts.
>
> Defined in RFC 2387

Another [great article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2011/04/21/mixed-ing-it-up-multipart-mixed-messages-and-you.aspx) referencing solutions by Microsoft Exchange.