# Html signature with embeded image

Tags: html, email

I'm having trouble with trying to create an email signature with an embeded image. The code is as follows:

**New code after last reply but still no joy**

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="outer-boundary"

This is a MIME-encoded message. If you are seeing this, your mail
reader is old.
--outer-boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

This message might make you :) or it might make you :(

--outer-boundary
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/html"; start="<body@here>"; boundary="inner-boundary"

--inner-boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-ID: <body@here>

<html>
<body>
<div class="container" style="width: 96%;height: auto;overflow:    hidden;padding: 2%;">

<div class="header" style="width: 100%;height: auto;overflow: hidden;">
<div class="header-left" style="width: 100px;height: 52px;">
<img src="cid:smile@here" alt="Worth Retail" style="width: 100px;">
</div>
<div class="header-right" style="width: 100%;">
<h1 style="font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;color: #68c4cf;padding: 10px 0 0 0;margin: 10px 0 0 0;">Alex Johns <span class="divide" style="font-weight: 100;padding: 0 5px 0 5px;">|</span> <span class="position" style="font-weight: 100;">Managing Partner</span></h1>
</div>
</div>

<div class="info">
<ul style="padding: 0;margin: 20px 0 0 0;">
<li class="phone" style="padding: 0 0 5px 28px;margin: 5px 0 0 0;letter-spacing: 1px;list-style: none;color: #2c2c2b;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;background: url(http://www.worthretail.com/email/img/icons.jpg) no-repeat;">+44 (0)207 428 6010 | +44 (0)7969 874318</li>
<li class="email" style="padding: 0 0 5px 28px;margin: 5px 0 0 0;letter-spacing: 1px;list-style: none;color: #2c2c2b;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;background: url(http://www.worthretail.com/email/img/icons.jpg) no-repeat 0 -30px;">alex@worthretail.com</li>
<li class="web" style="padding: 0 0 5px 28px;margin: 5px 0 0 0;letter-spacing: 1px;list-style: none;color: #2c2c2b;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;background: url(http://www.worthretail.com/email/img/icons.jpg) no-repeat 0 -58px;">worthretail.com</li>
<li class="location" style="padding: 0 0 5px 28px;margin: 5px 0 0 0;letter-spacing: 1px;list-style: none;color: #2c2c2b;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;background: url(http://www.worthretail.com/email/img/icons.jpg) no-repeat 0 -85px;padding-top: 3px;">503 Highgate Studios, London, NW5 1TL</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
 </html>

--inner-boundary
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <smile@here>

 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

--inner-boundary--

--outer-boundary--
```

I am new to all this so not sure if im even on the right track so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You wrapped your Content-Type to a second line on the HTML part.  That should be indented with white space or be all on one line.

Comment: Sorry I'm really struggling with this could you point out what part has wrapped?

Comment: Content-Type: multipart/related;
type="text/html"; start="<body@here>"; boundary="inner-boundary"

Comment: I've placed it all on one line but still not showing anything...

Answer (score 0):

This does not look much like a multipart MIME email.  There should not be any indentations - especially for the headers and boundaries.  The content-type of the overall email should be `multipart/mixed; boundary="------------090303020209010600070908"` and there should be a blank line after the end of the headers in each part.

Here is a good example here of basic MIME format with HTML:
[MIME type to satisfy  HTML, email, images and plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631856/mime-type-to-satisfy-html-email-images-and-plain-text)

You don't need to attach the logo.  As the other icons are included via HTTP with an IMG tag, it is best practice to link to images externally.  However, if you need to do it this way, you need to link to the attachment in your img tag:

```
<img alt="Worth Retail" src="cid:part1.06090408.01060107" style="width: 100px;">
```

Comment: So I've cleaned up the code but now im not seeing anything?

Comment: Paste your MIME email here for a lot more detail than I can give: http://tools.ietf.org/tools/msglint/