# JavaMail on Google App Engine sending HTML email with attachments - ignores first attachment

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I am using Java on Google App Engine and trying to send an email with multiple attachments.

What I am finding is that it is for some reason missing off the first attachment.
Basically if filesToAttach contains 1 file, then there will be no attachments.
If filesToAttach contains 4 files - A, B, C and D, then the message that comes through will have B, C and D attached. Really bizarre.

The code I am using is as below. Any suggestions as to how to rectify this greatly appreciated.

The output that the log.info calls generate appears to show the correct number of files have  been attached.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    String fromEmail = "admin@" + ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId() + ".appspotmail.com";
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, "MyApp Admin"));
    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, addresses);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    htmlPart.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html");
    multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

    for(FileToAttach fileToAttach : filesToAttach) {
      MimeBodyPart fileMimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
      DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(fileToAttach.getContents(), "application/octet-stream");
      fileMimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
      fileMimeBodyPart.setFileName(fileToAttach.getFileName());
      log.info("attaching file " + fileToAttach.getFileName() + " of " + fileToAttach.getContents().length + " bytes");
      multipart.addBodyPart(fileMimeBodyPart);
    }

    message.setContent(multipart);
    log.info("the multipart contains " + multipart.getCount() + " parts and isComplete = " + multipart.isComplete());
    Transport.send(message);
    log.info("called Transport.send");
```

Comment: An ugly workaround would be to put an empty dummy file as the first entry in filesToAttach ;-)  That delivers the desired result while you take more time to search for the right solution.  I'm inexperienced with multipart mail, but the symptoms suggest that the first attachment might be getting combined with the htmlPart, yet not displaying because it's not html formatted.  Try to add something that will delimit the end of the html body before you add the file attachments.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.  You might want to set the disposition of the attachments (setDisposition method), or simplify your code using the attachFile method.  Also, just before Transport.send, do message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt")) and then see if msg.txt has all the attachments.  If none of that provides clues, it may be that Google App Engine has a broken version of JavaMail.

Comment: It's possible the solution to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744197/best-practices-sending-javamail-mime-multipart-emails-and-gmail) (which I've observed on App Engine) may help. Although that relates to `multipart/alternative`, there may be a similar effect with attachments.  Perhaps the App Engine JavaMail implementation is expecting there to be a `text/plain` part to accompany the `text/html` body?

Comment: Aha. I think that might be along the right lines, because if I attach two images, the mime type of the first one is text/plain.
I seem to have got round it by doing `fileMimeBodyPart.SetHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")` (or "application/octet-stream"). But it could be a more elegant solution  to do setText on the multipart as well, I'll try it. Thanks a lot for the suggestion