# Not able to send html mail body along with xls file as attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using below code to send xls file and showing some data in tabular format.I am able to get xls file as an attachment but the html code is not coming in tabular format. If I uncomment **msg.setContent(body, "text/html")** line then i only get table format in body but the attachment is not there

```
public synchronized static void sendEmail(Session session, String toEmail, String subject, String body, String recipient) {
    try {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

//            msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/html");

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@xyz", "abc@xyz"));

        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));

        msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(recipient, false));

        msg.setSubject(subject);

        msg.setSentDate(new Date());



        //==================================================================
        // create and fill the first message part
        MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        mbp1.setText(body);
        // create the second message part
        MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        // attach the file to the message
        FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource("D:/Shashank/output.xls");
        mbp2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
        mbp2.setFileName(fds.getName());
        // create the Multipart and add its parts to it
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
        mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);
        // add the Multipart to the message
        msg.setContent(mp);
//            msg.setContent(body, "text/html");
        msg.saveChanges();

        //==================================================================  
       System.out.println("Message is ready");

       Transport.send(msg);

       System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully!!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a Content-Type header to your HTML body part.  `mbp1.addHeader("Content-type", "text/html");`

Comment: @RichardNeish: attachment was not present after adding this but table was in html format. plz help :(

Answer (score 0):

When you wish to send a body part (text) **and** a attachment, then you must create a mime multipart message.

For example with [plain java mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744197/best-practices-sending-javamail-mime-multipart-emails-and-gmail).

Or use the [apache commons email](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html) to handle this.

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.*;
...

// Create the attachment
EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
attachment.setPath("mypictures/john.jpg");
attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
attachment.setDescription("Picture of John");
attachment.setName("John");

// Create the email message
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
email.setHostName("mail.myserver.com");
email.addTo("jdoe@somewhere.org", "John Doe");
email.setFrom("me@apache.org", "Me");
email.setSubject("The picture");
email.setMsg("Here is the picture you wanted");

// add the attachment
email.attach(attachment);

// send the email
email.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code working 100% fine for me...

```
       File file;//Attached file
       MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EMAIL_FROM));
       final String[] to = emailsTo;
       // Create the message part
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent("", "text/html");
        message.setSubject("");
        /////////////Attach File/////////////
        // Create the message part
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent("", "text/html");
        // Create a multipart message
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // Set text message part
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Part two is attachment
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Send the complete message parts
        message.setContent(multipart, "text/html");
        /////////////////////////////////////
        Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use this :

#!/usr/bin/ksh

export MAILTO="spam@ebay.com"
export SUBJECT="Mail Subject"
export BODY="/tmp/email_body.html"
export ATTACH="/tmp/attachment.xls"
(
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-q1w2e3r4t5"'
 echo
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat $BODY
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
 echo 'Content-Type: application; name="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'

    uuencode -m $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH)

 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5--'
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
```

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with java/javamail