# error : javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart while reading the email content

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have the following code to read the Gmail email using Java. If the email is having very simple plain text message, then the code is working fine and I am able to see the content of the (body) being displayed properly.

But, for some emails I see the following message while I try to

> display body (CONTENT:javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@2038ae61)

. I am finding difficult to fix this issue. Please help me.

Code :

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Experiment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "username@gmail.com",
                    "password");
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
            Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
            for (Address address : in) {
                System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
            }

            // showContent(msg);


            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
            System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
            System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());


        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744197/best-practices-sending-javamail-mime-multipart-emails-and-gmail) answer may provide some insight

Comment: Hi, Thanks for pointing out to the post. Apparently, the post is pointing to the post explaining the sending of email. Here my problem is while reading the email content.

Answer (score 6):

**This as works for me**

```
  String contentType = msg.getContentType();
    String messageContent="";

   if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
        int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
        for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
        }
    }
    else if (contentType.contains("text/plain")
            || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
        Object content = message.getContent();
        if (content != null) {
            messageContent = content.toString();
        }
    }
     System.out.println(" Message: " + messageContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete file attachments reading solution:

```
    final Map<String, byte[]> attachments = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        if ( mailMessage.getContentType().contains("multipart") && mailMessage.getContent() instanceof Multipart ) {
            final Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) mailMessage.getContent();
            for ( int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++ ) {
                final MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
                if ( Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition()) ) {
                    final String fileName = MimeUtility.decodeText(part.getFileName());                        
                    final byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(part.getInputStream());
                    attachments.put(fileName, bytes);                    }
            }
        }
    } catch (final IOException | javax.mail.MessagingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    attachments.forEach(( f, c ) -> {
        System.out.println("filename: " + f + " content:" + new String(c));
    });
```