# Getting exception while sending mail through Java

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

Getting exception while sending mail through Java

exception is::

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.sun.mail.util.LineOutputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/OutputStream;Z)V
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1648)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1906)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1134)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at com.yodlee.SendMail.sendMail(SendMail.java:78)
at com.yodlee.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:32)
```

Here is the Java code::

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(SMTP_HOST_KEY,SMTP_HOST);

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(".....",
                    "#.......");
        }
    });

    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(RECIPIENT_FROM));
        message.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        //message.setText("Test mails111");


        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        messageBodyPart.setContent(data, "text/html");
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        status = -1;
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

I am getting error at Transport.send(msg);
Jars i am using here:: smtp 1.6.0, Javax Mail 1.4.7 , mailactivation

Comment: Do you set the mime type?

Comment: Apparently the order of the parts matters according to the multipart MIME spec, as per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744197/best-practices-sending-javamail-mime-multipart-emails-and-gmail

Answer (score 9):

Most likely you have multiple versions of the JavaMail classes on your class path.  Check all your dependencies and your application server environment for conflicts.  If more than one jar file contains the javax.mail.* or com.sun.mail.* classes, you have a problem.

And be sure to fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), and definitely be sure to use the [latest version of JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).

Answer (score 2):

I fix the issue:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.sun.mail.util.LineOutputStream.(java.io.OutputStream, boolean)'

Added in my pom.xml the dependencies com.sun.mail with same version of the javax.mail-api

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

check your jar's version,try to change some versions，if it is a 'maven project',check the enviroment dependencies.as you know,java's enviroment usually follows with errores,you may be careful.

Comment: I have tried with javax mail 1.4.7 , 1.5.1, 1.6.0, but still i am getting the error