# Sending multipart mail in java with inline HTML

Tags: java, html, email, multipart

I am working on sending multipart email. My first part of the email is text and the second part is html. I followed

[Best Practices - Sending javamail mime multipart emails - and gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744197/best-practices-sending-javamail-mime-multipart-emails-and-gmail)

but instead doing:

`Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");`

I am doing:

`Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");`

This is triggering HTML part of the mail as attachment in outlook. However, gmail works just fine for the same code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *Any suggestions?* - why don't you follow the accepted answer in the link you provided?

Comment: I am sending two parts (text+html) in the email and both are meant to be displayed. So i can't choose 'alternative'.