# Multipart/alternative with attachments

Tags: php, email

I'm trying create a `multipart/mixed` email with `multipart/alternative` (html/text) as one part and the attachment(s) as the other part.

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902455/smtp-multipart-alternative-vs-multipart-mixed)
, but couldn't get it to work.

What I did find out was to use `multipart/alternative` within `multipart/mixed`, with different boundaries.

I found an example [here](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php?print=Y). This example looks like what I was looking for, but my code doesn't work. I get either an empty email with 3 attachents(.dat,.html & .pdf), or an an empty email with one binary '.dat' attachment.

What's wrong with my code:

```
Date: Sun, 08 Sep 2013 10:38:15 +0700
Subject: Login details for Test
To: test@test.com
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:Mail.class.php
from: no_reply@localhost
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="38651c4450f87348fcbe1f992746a954"

--38651c4450f87348fcbe1f992746a954
Content-Type: mixed/alternative; boundary="sub_38651c4450f87348fcbe1f992746a954"

--sub_38651c4450f87348fcbe1f992746a954
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Plain text message

--sub_38651c4450f87348fcbe1f992746a954
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Dear [realname],<br><br>

You've requested to resend your login credentials for Test.<br><br>

<b>HTML</b> message

--sub_38651c4450f87348fcbe1f992746a954--

--38651c4450f87348fcbe1f992746a954
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="test.pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="test.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAy
IDAgUgovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFI+PgplbmRvYmoKNCAwIG9iago8PC9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVj
etc, etc

--38651c4450f87348fcbe1f992746a954--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `mixed/alternative` when it should be `multipart/alternative`.

Comment: That did it! Looks like I was blinded while staring at my own code. Thanks Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

Better try using **PHPMailer**. Its is very easy to use ad configure. In example directory, you can see the solution for multiple attachments also. I'm using this.

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer