# Set Zend_Mime_Message as Zend_Mail body

Tags: email, zend-framework, zend-mail

I'm trying to send `email` with inline images and attachments with `Zend Framework 1`.

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_MIXED);
$mail->setSubject('Message');
$mail->setFrom('user@example1.com', 'Example user #1');
$mail->addTo('user@example2.com', 'Example user #2');
```

And trying to make `nested email`, by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16554976/542420).

```
message
  mainMultipart (content for message, subType="related")
    ->htmlAndTextBodyPart (bodyPart1 for mainMultipart)
      ->htmlAndTextMultipart (content for htmlAndTextBodyPart)
        ->htmlBodyPart (bodyPart1 for htmlAndTextMultipart)
          ->html (content for htmlBodyPart)
        ->textBodyPart (bodyPart2 for the htmlAndTextMultipart)
          ->text (content for textBodyPart)
    ->fileBodyPart1 (bodyPart2 for the mainMultipart)
      ->FileDataHandler (content for fileBodyPart1)
```

**Small Example:**

```
$html               = '<p>Hello</p>';
$bodyHtmlPart       = new Zend_Mime_Part($html);
$bodyHtmlPart->type = Zend_Mime::TYPE_HTML;

$bodyMsg            = new Zend_Mime_Message();
$bodyMsg->addPart($bodyHtmlPart);

// And other nesting.. ending with Zend_Mime_Message
```

**Question:**

How to set `Zend_Mime_Message` to `Zend_Mail` body? Below added couple `Zend_Mail` functions, not really helpful.

```
$mail->setBodyHtml( ? );
$mail->setBodyText( ? );
```

I tried to look at `Zend_Mail_Message` function, but look alike it only works with `ZF2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
$mailObject->setParts($mimeMessageObject->getParts());
```

?

Answer (score 0):

For inline images here is a class someone wrote for it:
http://davidnussio.wordpress.com/2008/09/21/inline-images-into-html-email-with-zend-framework/

If your wanting to send as an attachment, then its plain and simple from the docs:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();

$at = $mail->createAttachment($myImage);
$at->type        = 'image/gif';
$at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
$at->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$at->filename    = 'test.gif';

$mail->send();
```

Notice how on both Zend's example and that class from the link both have the following set for the disposition.

```
Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
```

Zend Docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.attachments.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Problem I'm facing: can't have inline image attachments and attached files displayed properly. That's why I'm doing `multipart MIME nesting`. Answer not really match question.

Comment: Well duh I know they aren't displaying properly, I didn't write this answer to help show you how to display bananas.