# Inline image rendered twice by OSX mail app

Tags: asp.net, smtp, .net-4.5, smtpclient

My .NET 4.5 web application uses class [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to create and send e-mail messages to various recipients.
Each e-mail message consists of:

- an HTML message body
- an embedded inline image (JPeg or PNG or GIF)
- an attachment (PDF)

Sample code is below. It works fine, but there is one gripe from OSX users. Apple's standard mail app renders the image twice; once inlined in the message body, and again following the message body, next to the preview of the PDF attachment.

---

[image: Screenshot Apple Mail, faulty message]

---

I tinkered with the following properties; none of which would help.

- [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)'s DeliveryFormat
- [MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx)'s IsBodyHtml and BodyTransferEncoding
- [Attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx)'s MimeType, Inline, DispositionType, ContentId, FileName, Size, CreationDate, ModificationDate

If I compose a similar e-mail message in MS Outlook and send it off to the Apple user, the image is rendered once, inlined in the message body; exactly as I would like it to be. So apparently it *is* possible.
After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902455/smtp-multipart-alternative-vs-multipart-mixed), I inspected the raw MIME data, and noticed Outlook uses `multipart/related` to group together the message body and the images.

---

[image: Screenshot Apple Mail, message from Outlook]

---

**My question:**
How do I mimic Outlook's behavior with the classes found in [System.Net.Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Things I would rather not do:

- Employ external images instead of embedded ones (many e-mail clients initially block these to protect recipient's privacy).
- Use third party libraries (to avoid legal hassle). The SmtpDirect class I found [here](http://blog.devexperience.net/en/12/Send_an_Email_in_CSharp_with_Inline_attachments.aspx) seems to solve the problem (though I got a server exception in return), but it is hard for me to accept a complete rewrite of MS's SmtpClient implementation is necessary for such a subtle change.
- Send the e-mail message to a pickup folder, manipulate the resulting `.eml` file, push the file to our Exchange server.

Minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;

namespace SendMail
{
    class Program
    {
        const string body = "Body text <img src=\"cid:ampersand.gif\" /> image.";

        static Attachment CreateGif()
        {
            var att = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(Resource1.ampersand), "ampersand.gif")
            {
                ContentId = "ampersand.gif",
                ContentType = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif)
            };
            att.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
            return att;
        }

        static Attachment CreatePdf()
        {
            var att = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(Resource1.Hello), "Hello.pdf")
            {
                ContentId = "Hello.pdf",
                ContentType = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf)
            };
            att.ContentDisposition.Inline = false;
            return att;
        }

        static MailMessage CreateMessage()
        {
            var msg = new MailMessage(Resource1.from, Resource1.to, "The subject", body)
            {
                IsBodyHtml = true
            };
            msg.Attachments.Add(CreateGif());
            msg.Attachments.Add(CreatePdf());
            return msg;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new SmtpClient(Resource1.host).Send(CreateMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

To actually build and run it, you will need an additional resource file `Resource1.resx` with the two attachments (`ampersand` and `Hello`) and three strings `host` (the SMTP server), `from` and `to` (both of which are e-mail addresses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I found this solution myself before I got to posting the question, but decided to publish anyway; it may help out others. I am still open for alternative solutions!)

I managed to get the desired effect by using class [AlternateView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.alternateview(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
static MailMessage CreateMessage()
{
    var client = new SmtpClient(Resource1.host);
    var msg = new MailMessage(Resource1.from, Resource1.to, "The subject", "Alternative message body in plain text.");
    var view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    var res = new LinkedResource(new MemoryStream(Resource1.ampersand), new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif))
    {
        ContentId = "ampersand.gif"
    };
    view.LinkedResources.Add(res);
    msg.AlternateViews.Add(view);
    msg.Attachments.Add(CreatePdf());
    return msg;
}
```

---

[image: Screenshot Apple Mail, fixed message]

---

As a side effect, the message now also contains a plain text version of the body (for paranoid web clients that reject HTML). Though it is a bit of a burden ("Alternative message body in plain text" needs improvement), it does give you more control as to how the message is rendered under different security settings.