# Embedded images are shown as attachement in commons mail 1.4

Tags: java, email

I am sending HTML emails with embedded images by using the following code:

```
    HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    email.setCharset("utf-8");
    String html=....;
    String txt=....;

    Map map=new HashMap();
    map.put("charset",CHARSET);
    map.put("List-Unsubscribe","<mailto:abc@example.com>, <https://example.com/");
    map.put("X-property", property);
    email.setHeaders(map);

    email.setHostName(HOSTNAME);
    email.setSmtpPort(PORT);
    email.setFrom(from, fromname);
    email.setBounceAddress(frombounce);
    email.setSubject(subject);
    Iterator<String> it=inlineImages.iterator();
    URL url=null;
    String cid = "";
    String imgurl ="";
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
            imgurl=it.next();
            url = (getPathFromLocalFile(imgurl));
            cid = email.embed(url, getName(imgurl));
            html=StringTools.replace(html,imgurl,"cid:"+cid);
    }
    email.addTo(to);
    email.setTextMsg(textbody);
    email.setHtmlMsg(htmlbody);
    email.setHostName(HOSTNAME);
    .....
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.send();
```

The code works fine, as I receive a nice Email in the end. The images are embedded and in Thunderbird, the user immediately sees the correct html with images.
However, there are some clients that don't work properly. Those are Outlook, K9-Mail for Android or Roundcube. Here, I see the paperclip symbol for attachements. Nevertheless, the mail looks great, so no need to press a button to download them. Probably something is wrong with the Content-Type of the mail, but I am not sure about this.

Can anyone see whats wrong?

EDIT:
Heres the header as plain text.

> Return-Path:  X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin
>   3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on test@example.com X-Spam-Level:  X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.9 required=4.0 tests=BAYES_00,FREEMAIL_FROM,
>   HTML_MESSAGE,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2,SPF_PASS,URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=ham
>   autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0 X-Original-To: test@example.com
>   Delivered-To: test@example.com Received: from mout.example.net
>   (mout.example.net [77.77.77.77])  (using TLSv1.2 with cipher
>   DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits))  (No client certificate
>   requested)  by mail.example.eu (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 7275A7AB8687 
>   for ; Fri, 10 Jun 2016 15:41:56 +0200 (CEST)
>   Received: from example ([77.77.77.77]) by mail.example.com
>   (mrexample001) with ESMTPSA  (Nemesis) id 0Lw2Sj-1bWOaM07n3-017j0o for
>   ;  Fri, 10 Jun 2016 15:41:55 +0200 Date: Fri, 10 Jun
>   2016 15:41:47 +0200 (CEST) From:  Testaccount von example
>    To: test@example.com Message-ID:
>   <809223752.3.1465566107118.JavaMail.user@example> Subject:
>   =?UTF-8?Q?Sch=C3=BCtzen_Sie_sich_mit_unanfec?=  =?UTF-8?Q?= MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>   boundary="----=_Part_0_1010418160.1465566107019" charset: utf-8
>   X-Customer: 12u890812792 List-Unsubscribe: , 
>   https://example.com/method=unsubscribe&email=12u890812792&unsubscribe=true
>   X-Provags-ID:
>   V03:K0:+WezTQKC0rV+i+/Dkvjm1Zp0+w6o6ZGZNXBvIMdU0ANaUTEIxow 
>   63iaYyDyxW74ZNkXdFRiDea9DyQdordqCoprE2tJEhtDIS+ceHt+Q9eb+tSCyf1ADE6bZja
>   NDJKYXWJdW0NeAZydDcVP/8Er5knlmumhlyEhlnjFGmqbiBuO4wP3KqqC3vkh5rYFVaZe9V
>   pM8Mox3lSMx4V/gh7Tp0g== X-UI-Out-Filterresults:
>   notjunk:1;V01:K0:twqiq4jOtPg=:bALN2jRhEVBD8MkqJgqyHi 
>   FerpGKfqCgKcqiw2MdjebvuPKTI12CaGUIBMBiionmrMEmEXNENQNV/xK6b+8QAYHLixWQqZc
>   TC9lJFf8r2OcEpyNnFlNTHm8c/b/GbbOR/TUfk9W487HaXattRdnfsiZH/eFRiPcGB9y4gtZY
>   G03G7U0rFPTcIvvHG10Ubc5eWq7v+Ptm6G9emlihE0Axc0flWW8K/j8Xat1l5KZ2OksQFrSAH
>   YJlOEmoQM87W56bpqmZ+3T8/qUVDpdrV5KTdf0Y6wekk4lB3Po421sddZALqvWWZbWPBHS5Ce
>   gFyTSfT55Gc38mDtoEABkWWJC7n15yci/MXkcHzvyHswMli3pGu6Gv5YteG6w0aVHP2FTtNgJ
>   nn/6aWdDITy8SVr03WdWKN+aNERwt79aTVorOE5RBqDuYk7DN8i190nNEEfgL1dRjF+Zx+31o
>   Xvh6rYSN1anm7CxVC06VbstGLY6Rrq0Ore+5s+Obv+X20FL/ao2LwqtJ96EiRcKsO1H+T5t1F
>   HEEscuUO0yASaWDxXVb+uoYy06IwgITc0TwuLZ1qGUxtIIIy4CIvZEw68CbAih3BFstV8zRid
>   DLFrdHtf+hBfon1P4uRp5kkyB+47w7G1Or3bPISqp/zhdq7LsYbFP5AuwXzGcQdP7IPAbeIGp
>   oGUCTm74nqITGbfW/jqV27c1viJn3GEGHt90HmyYNJHqGS/dW2wiaeQhgIV+Wp/Pm7cb/GwgB
>   qAx54/FxoLO4nR5wvLqcUNlsO1t7xepEBl5puvmWyLZR++AsnEhcK/6ZqdQ=
>   X-Virus-Status: No X-Virus-Checker-Version: clamassassin 1.2.4 with
>   clamdscan / ClamAV
>    0.98.7/21704/Fri Jun 10 11:44:45 2016 X-Spambayes-Classification: ham; 0.03 X-Virustotal-Status: No X-Virustotal-String: # not
>   checked:none/text/plain# not  checked:none/text/html# not
>   checked:1465566109864.png/image/png# not 
>   checked:1465566121103.png/image/png# not
>   checked:1465566117059.png/image/png#  not
>   checked:1465566110651.png/image/png# not 
>   checked:1465566109052.png/image/png# not
>   checked:1465566113630.png/image/png#  not
>   checked:1465566121054.png/image/png# not 
>   checked:1465566115535.png/image/png# not
>   checked:1465566109346.png/image/png#  not
>   checked:1465566114750.png/image/png# not 
>   checked:1465566108289.png/image/png# not
>   checked:1465566113027.png/image/png#  not
>   checked:1465566115345.png/image/png# not 
>   checked:1465566117438.png/image/png# not
>   checked:1465566119754.png/image/png

Comment: You should show the headers of a generated mail so that we can see whether something is non standard...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I've added the header, put probably it is not very nice to read...

Comment: Unsure whether it is or not a duplicate, but you could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902455/smtp-multipart-alternative-vs-multipart-mixed BTW: next time try to give the raw headers not all lines joined with `> ` anywhere in between :-(

Comment: Actually this doesn't really fit my problem @SergeBallesta

Comment: Assume you are using Apache commons mail, you could try to set the content-type to Multipart/Alternative instead of the default Multipart/Mixed, but really unsure of it (that's why it's a comment and not an answer...) - `email.updateContentType("multipart/alternative;");`