# SMTP Rich text field at protocol header

Tags: smtp, rtf

I would like to know if at SMTP specification there is a field where we can specify that it is a rich text and maybe the type of rich text, like RTF for example? Or we just send some RTF text at SMTP payload and let the client handle it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1):

You have to use multipart email for this with the appropriate MIME. Your question has already been answered: [Mail multipart/alternative vs multipart/mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902455/mail-multipart-alternative-vs-multipart-mixed#3984262)

Comment: The title of the other question is already part of the solution, which is much harder to find than my question.