# How we can use image in email template in keycloak locally

Tags: keycloak

```
<img src="${url.resourcesPath}/images/logo.png" />
```

Problem: Above code path is working in `template.ftl` but same thing not working in email template.

In email template we have try with various options but `baseUrl` and `rootUrl` also not coming there.

Comment: a shame that keycloak still does not address this issue. I've seen threads from 5 years ago and keycloak version 4.0.0, now we're sitting at 14.0.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57692616/keycloak-add-company-logo-to-the-reset-password-email      -- is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

if you have the next image path:

```
\themes\as2theme\login\resources\img\test.png
```

you can refer it from an image tag like this

```
<img src="${url.resourcesPath}/img/test.png"/>
```

also you can see this post:
https://codehumsafar.wordpress.com/2018/09/21/keycloak-add-image-in-custom-theme/

Answer (score 1):

We can use ${url.resourcesCommonPath}

1. File location **(keycloak/themes/lnsw/email/theme.properties)**.
   Add the following line to the theme.properties file

   basePath=http://localhost:5005

   phoneIcon=/img/alpha124.png

eg. [image]

2. Create a folder structure for image resources as follows
   **(keycloak/themes/keycloak/common/resources/img/alpha124.png)**
   [image]
3. Use the following code in the .ftl template file
   [image]

Comment: There is no ${url} in scope of email-test, at least at Keycloak 19.0.2 your approach does not work. If you take look on FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java you will not find "url" for sendSmtpTestEmail but for some reason "url" is set for almost all others emails.
So had better not to use {url} in scope of common template.ftl and email-test.

Comment: how about if we have a react or vue format file that be handled by webpack. the path of images don't work when generating .ftl format