# I don't receive the attachment

Tags: python, smtplib, thunderbird

I'm sending an e-mail through smtplib in Python with a xlsx file in attachment. I can open the attachment in Gmail website, but in Thunderbird the file doesn't appear.

I need to use Thunderbird because it is the preferred tool to the client that I'm working for.

```py
import smtplib, ssl
from email import encoders
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase


def enviar_email(email):
    smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    port = 465
    sender = 'proex.crim@gmail.com'
    password = '**********'
    receiver = email
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    message['Subject'] = 'Pesquisa finalizada'
    message['From'] = sender
    message['To'] = receiver
    filename = f'C:\\Users\\evand\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\projeto\\core\\funcoes\\{email}.xlsx'



    with open(filename, 'rb') as attachment:
        part_a = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stram')
        part_a.set_payload(attachment.read())
        filename = 'Resultado da Pesquisa.xlsx'

    encoders.encode_base64(part_a)

    text = f"""\
        Olá, segue em anexo o resultado da pesquisa solicitada no nosso site. 
        Enviamos para você um arquivo com os processos correspondentes aos CNPJs pesquisados.
    
    
    """

    html = """\
        <html>
            <body>
            <p> Olá, segue em anexo o resultado da pesquisa solicitada no nosso site. <br>
            </p>
            <p> Enviamos para você um arquivo com os processos correspondentes aos CNPJs pesquisados.</p>
        </body>
    </html>
    
    """

    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    part_a.add_header(
        'Content-Disposition',
        f'attachment; filename= {filename}',
    )

    message.attach(part1)
    message.attach(part2)
    message.attach(part_a)

    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender, password)
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message.as_string())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm in no way an expert but multipart/alternative should be the "mail" part only, IMHO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902455/mail-multipart-alternative-vs-multipart-mixed/28833772

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm not an expert too, I started to work with that this year, and you solve my problem. I just changed multipart/alternative to multipart/mixed.

Comment: glad I could help : I was puzzled when Thunderbird did not work, it _had_ to be "your fault" :-p