# Email from PHP seems to put headers in the body

Tags: php, email

I am trying to get an MMS app for FusionPBX working. It receives MMS through email. Everything works fine for SMS, however, when I try to receive an MMS message the email comes through with headers in the body. This is what is in the body:

```
Msg: MMS Message received, see attachment-- 
==Multipart_Boundary_x33841fa48df5ecbc2f23291f4780c374x
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
name = "0035894183d467fde82b2795989375c5ad1fa17538a3b0388f15b76c1a7cf968.jpeg"
Content-Disposition: inline;
filename = "0035894183d467fde82b2795989375c5ad1fa17538a3b0388f15b76c1a7cf968.jpeg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
```

Followed by what I assume is the base64 encoded data for the attachment.

This is the code that I believe is causing the issue:

```
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
                        " name = \"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" . "Content-Disposition: inline;\n" . " filename = \"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                        "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n\n" . $attdata . "\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is the error you're experiencing?

Comment: @parttimeturtle The attachment is coming through in the body as base64 encoded characters and some of the headers are in the body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remember `"\n\n"` before each `"--{$mime_boundary}\n"` (better than after: `$email_message .= ... . $attdata . "\n\n"` )

(maybe you didn't rmmber? : is "`see attachment--==Multipart_Boundary"`, should be "`...see attachment\n\n--==Multipart_Boundary...`")

2. Is definition in message header? Should be i.e.

`$email_additionalheader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary={$mime_boundary}\n"`

3. Seen these? : i.e. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages), [Mail multipart/alternative vs multipart/mixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902455),  [RFC2045](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2045.html), [RFC1341](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2045.html) etc.